# How do I make city-wise pages with a single template in WordPress WP-Bakery or any plugin for multiple pages?

Tags: wordpress, elementor, wordpress-shortcode, wpbakery

How do I make city-wise pages with a single template in WordPress WP-Bakery or any plugin for multiple pages. Same template used at a time so that I can change section easily

Comment: Simple create page from wp dashboard with city slug or create multiple categories with city name and assign post city wise and you can use categories as a page from  menu tab or customized

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using URL parameter with your single page. like https://example.com/city/?name=kolkata

If you want nice URL structure like https://example.com/city/kolkata/ then you need to use WordPress [Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)

Now inside the single page you need to use a custom shortcode, which will catch the city name from URL and output your some dynamic data as per your requirements.